# If  is an odd function and lim→0 () exists then prove that lim→0 ()=0.

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]

a/ Give an example of a function such that ∗(0) exists but lim→0 () does not exist.

b/ If  is an odd function (i.e., ()=−(−) for all ∗(0)=0) and lim→0 () exists then prove that lim→0 ()=0.

Hello, I am struggling with this question. Where to begin? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Think about it.  If the limit were anything else, for example a positive number $C$, then as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, $f(x)$ would get closer and closer to $C$.  What would have to happen as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$.  Obviously for any function $h$, we have

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} h(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} h(-x).$$

Then

$$C = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(-x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} -f(x) = - \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = -C  $$

so $C = 0$.

Comment: Wow thank you! This helps so much! How about question a??

Comment: Think about what $f^*$ means